# Angular 2 - three JS - ply files working on Firefox and Safari but crashing in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, safari, three.js

This is driving me insane. I have an Angular 2 app that uses THREE JS and the PLY file loader. It work in all platform if I use small STL files and small PLY files. The code used is the same that you can find here:

[THREE JS - PLYLoader](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ply)

Unfortunately I need to load very big ply files 1,000,000 vertices and 3,000,000 faces. In Chrome the app crashes as it always exceed 2.2 GB of memory. The app works very slowly in Safari but rocks in Firefox.

I cannot force my clients to work on Safari. Can you suggest a way to make the app working on all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution I have adopted was to decimate my file using the free software MeshLab.

Hope this helps someone.

Dino